# Project Orleans Cannot find grain implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, orleans

I have a solution in .NET 7 version. I am using Orleans 7.0.2 version in this solution.

I have 3 projects in my solution named Contracts, Grains and ConsoleApp.

I have IStock.cs interface in my Contracts project:

```
public interface IStock : IGrainWithIntegerKey
{
    Task<int> Get();
}
```

In my Grains project, I have the StockGrain.cs class and it uses the IStock.cs interface:

```
public class StockGrain : Grain, IStock
{
    public Task<int> Get()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(10);
    }
}
```

ConsoleApp project references 2 other projects. I am using the sample code as below in the Program.cs file:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseOrleans(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseLocalhostClustering();
    }).Build();

await host.StartAsync();

var client = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IGrainFactory>();
var grain = client.GetGrain<IStock>(1);

await host.StopAsync();
```

When I run ConsoleApp I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Could not find an implementation for interface Contracts.IStock
   at Orleans.GrainInterfaceTypeToGrainTypeResolver.GetGrainType(GrainInterfaceType interfaceType)
```

In Orleans 7 version, the Grain class I implemented cannot be found.

Comment: which NuGet package are you using for `Orleans `?

Comment: The Contracts and Grains projects have the **Microsoft.Orleans.Core.Abstractions** package installed.
In the ConsoleApp project, the **Microsoft.Orleans.Server** and **Microsoft.Orleans.CodeGenerator** packages are installed. All packages are in version 7.0.2. @VivekNuna

Comment: Try adding line `builder.AddGrain(typeof(StockGrain));` after `builder.UseLocalhostClustering();`

Comment: It says AddGrain method not found during the build phase. Also, can all grains be added automatically? @VivekNuna

Comment: are you able to use `RegisterGrain`?

Comment: I tried but unfortunately not found. @VivekNuna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install Microsoft.Orleans.Sdk into your Contracts and Grains projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/code-generation?pivots=orleans-7-0#enable-code-generation). Without it code generation doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, installing the Microsoft.Orleans.Sdk package worked.